# We need to force "http" for a single url . We already have a redirect of all urls to https

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

Our site https://www.globalcompanyformation.co.uk/ has a redirect to "https://" in the web.config file for all urls .

Now we have a form which sends information to our subdomain which is hosted in another ip address and which is not secure . This form is in our page https://www.globalcompanyformation.co.uk/Gcf-index.html . Firefox gives a warning message that the site to which you are redirected is not secure . We dont want to see this alert and when i checked whole internet the only solution was that i get the page "Gcf-index.html" to have "http" and not "https" .

Is there any way that i could force Gcf-index.html to open in "http" . The web.config coding is as follows as of now for redirecting to https for all urls .

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <clear />
      <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" negate="true" pattern="^Gcf-index.*" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: The solution is to secure the other page, not make the current one insecure.

Comment: @Quentin Why would you force SSL on a different domain just because a form makes a post to it? It could very well just be a contact form with no need to protect the enquiry or feedback details.

Comment: Because SSL is cheap, [SSL is better for SEO](http://searchengineland.com/google-starts-giving-ranking-boost-secure-httpsssl-sites-199446), and because SSL should be the default. We don't use postcards for most snail mail correspondence, why should we use cleartext on the Internet?

Comment: @Quentin Ha ha.. Thanks for making me laugh :)

Comment: ssl is cheap , thats y our site already has ssl .. but we have purchased a software from a site who dont use ssl on their site and thats where the form goes . so thats y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second condition to

```
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" negate="true" pattern="Gcf-index\.html" />
```

---

Add the following rule to force `http` on that form page.

```
<rule name="Force http on GCF" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="Gcf-index\.html$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}"
            redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help . but the problem is that index.html ( ie our main page) is using ssl and from there when gcf-index.html is accessed as we have a link to that ... it comes in https mode

Comment: Thankyou so much @ravi . You made my day Kudos . Awesome.... i have been trying to solve this for long ... thankyou so much :)

Comment: Happy to help, Pearl :)